# Show span content in other element after span's parent is hovered jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, show-hide

I'm trying to figure out how to make it so that when you hover a box, the element's span's text shows in a specific div.

http://jsfiddle.net/zACX4/

**HTML**

```
<ul id="specs">
  <li><a id="img1" href=""><span>ldldld</span></a></li>
  <li><a id="img2" href=""><span>ldldld</span></a></li>
  <li><a id="img3" href=""><span>ldldld</span></a></li>
  <li><a id="img4" href=""><span>ldldld</span></a></li>
  <li><a id="img5" href=""><span>ldldld</span></a></li>
  <li><a id="img6" href=""><span>ldldld</span></a></li>
  <li id="mid"><div id="specs_detail"></div></li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#specs li a').hover(function(){  

    var toLoad = $(this).find('span');
    $('#specs_detail p').fadeOut('fast',loadContent);
    function loadContent() {
        $('#specs_detail p').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
    }  
    function showNewContent() {  
        $('#specs_detail p').fadeIn('fast');
    }  
    return false;
 });  
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you have a few things that are not working. I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zACX4/1/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#specs li a').hover(function(){        
        var toLoad = $(this).find('span').text();

        $('#specs_detail').fadeOut('fast',loadContent);
        function loadContent() {
            $('#specs_detail').html(toLoad);
            showNewContent();
        }  
        function showNewContent() {  
            $('#specs_detail').fadeIn('fast');
        }  
        return false;
    });  
});
```

To insert html, use the `.html` function instead of `.load`. Also, `#specs_detail` doesn't contain any `p` element, so you can't select it, just use the div, or add a `p` element to it. Finaly, the variable toLoad contained the span element, use the `.text` function to get its content. Hope that helps.

Comment: Now, is there a way for it to stop fading out and back in when I remove my cursor from the element?